# Alarmmanager.set() always fires when application starts instead of expected time

Tags: java, android

I need to create an application to run a method at a specific time. However, AlarmManager never works, and I do not understand why. I set up the alarm to run at 11.54, but it always runs when the application starts and never runs at the expected time. If you know what is the problem, please comment. Thank you very much.

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.spr.timemanager">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TimeManager"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALARM"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my MainActivity.java

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0 , intent, 0);
    time = (calendar.getTimeInMillis() - (calendar.getTimeInMillis() % 60000));
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Log.e("time", String.valueOf(time));

    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pendingIntent);}
        else {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pendingIntent);}
    }else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pendingIntent);
    }
```

My AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(4000);
        Log.e("System time", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

This is my logcat

```
2022-05-25 11:52:27.820 16914-16914/com.spr.timemanager E/time: 1653468840000
2022-05-25 11:52:28.103 16914-16914/com.spr.timemanager E/System time: 1653468748103
```

P/S: if I change these alarmManager.set() code into setreapeating(), it always fires when the application starts and 5 seconds afterward, no matter how I set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calculating your `time` (when alarm should fire)

```
time = (calendar.getTimeInMillis() - (calendar.getTimeInMillis() % 60000));
```

but at very last after logging you are overriding this variable with

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

just before `if` cascade. remove this line, looks unnecessary

btw. `HOUR_OF_DAY` is in `<0 to 23>`, so if you want 11:54 exacly then you should set `10`. you can also set seconds and millis with `Calendar.SECOND` and `Calendar.MILLISECOND` to `0` instead of dividing with `%` and then your `time = calendar.getTimeInMillis()`

ps. you should add some alarm-in-past-setting protection (add a day?)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); // remember set -1 in here!!
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// ensuring next day
while (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Log.e("time", String.valueOf(time));

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0 , intent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    ... set alarm for time
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize I just set time to System time. I guess I lose my sanity when I find out my Alarm does not trigger on some devices. Also, I do not need past protection since it will only be triggered at the end of the day.

Comment: setting alarm for 11:54 (assuming AM) at the end of the day (e.g. 23:59) is in fact setting alarm in past with posted code ;) (still whole date is untouched, same day parsed from systems's timestamp) hope finding this mistake fixed your problem, good luck

Comment: So, if I use calendar to set it to 23:55, it will always perceive as an alarm to the past and always fires immediately? Will it fire at 11:55PM that night?

Comment: if you are setting alarm on 23:55 and you are changing only HOUR_OF_DAY and MINUTE you still may set it in the past (e.g. when your setting code gets called at 23:59 same day). you should check and calcualte this with your `calendar` instance and add one day to it with `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`

Comment: note that some countries are chaning time on summer/winter, so raw adding 24h in millis may result setting for wrong hour (+1 or -1 at the day of time switched). and calling calendar.add(... may cause adding not 24h in millis, but 23 or 25, depends on timezone set and possible time changes in it. rare case, but worth covering. check out my ans edit and snippet

Comment: My country has daylight saving time. Do I need to add or subtract 1 hour to the calendar when daylight saving time is off or something? At the moment, it works normally (we currently have DST here).

Comment: just test this: set proper date on phone (manual) and check :) imho there is no need to add/subtract as using `calendar.add(...` should check/do this for you